# Reportbuilder 3.0. Background PatternType Automatic for Graphs?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

Is there the  possibility to set the Background Pattern Style to Automatic. Would be really useful if the customer wants to print the report in Black and White.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a paramater, I suggest a boolean of `@auto`, if you want the customer to specify the Automatic background in lou of the corporate one.

As the background colour is a text field `Automatic` is the text you want.

Use the following formula in the expression field:

```
=IIf(@auto, "Automatic", "Corporate")
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I ment. I just wana have instead of a automatic coloure pallete a automatic Pattern Pallete.

Comment: A similar expression should work on the pattern pallete. Try different text for the palletes?